# Android Backup of Shared Preferences to Google Backup Service not working

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-backup-service

I've researched and followed how to get my android app to backup the data to google backup so if user loses phone or upgrades to a new phone, they don't lose their data.  However, when I test it out (by using the app myself, then uninstalling and reinstalling), no data is restored.  Here's what I've done.  Perhaps someone can figure out what is wrong.

1. Applied for a backup key from google
2. Placed following code in Manifest File (in place of key I did add the key value and for packageName I used my app package name)

   ```
   android:backupAgent="packageName.MyPrefsBackup">
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" android:value="key" />
   ```
3. Created class `MyPrefsBackup` with following code.  The name of the sharedpreference file I want to backup is called UserDB.  As far as the `PREFS_BACKIP_KEY`, I just called it prefs. From what I understand, this is not the same key as the one that goes in the manifest file.

Code:

```
package packageName;

import android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper;

import android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper;

public class MyPrefsBackup extends BackupAgentHelper {

    // The name of the SharedPreferences file

    static final String PREFS = "UserDB";

    // A key to uniquely identify the set of backup data

    static final String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "prefs";

    // Allocate a helper and add it to the backup agent

  public  void onCreate() {

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);


    }
}
```

1. Added `BackupManager mBackupManager = new BackupManager(this);` in my main class where I call the backup manager in next step
2. Lastly, in my main program I call the `backupHelper` when data is changed by the following line:

   ```
   mBackupManager.dataChanged();
   ```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try new BackupManager(this).dataChanged()

Comment: Thanks,  I'll give that a try for a few days and report back if it works.  I forgot to add above that I had the script BackupManager mBackupManager = new BackupManager(this);  in the variable declaration section of my main app.

Comment: So, this is still not working.  I test it out by installing the app from the market, then making edits to the database which invokes the dataChanged() command.  Then I wait about 2-3 days , uninstall the app and reinstall it.  Upon reinstalling, I am not prompted to reload the database.  Frustrating......any further help from someone?

Comment: You are only backuping the SharedPrefs. You did not backup the databases and files. That is the problem I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing this from AVD - you'll need to enable backups - AVD are disabled for backups by default.
adb shell bmgr enable true

Then you can actually debug it to see if the onCreate is called after running
adb shell bmgr run